Eclipse IDE in MacOS: how to set an environment variable from an AWS CLI execution? (for setting AWS Code Artifact Token)
I'm trying to use our AWS Code Artifact as Maven repository. That repo is set up to authenticate via a token, which expires every 24 hours. The token is retrieved from AWS via its CLI using aws codeartifact get-authorization-token .... So I need a way to set an environment variable to the value of that token prior to running a Maven build in Eclipse. Preferably without restarting the IDE.
I found a way for it to work in bare Terminal: I simply used mavenrc file with a script to set an environment variable if the token is expired. Then I referenced that variable in my custom settings.xml. That way every time I run mvn - it automatically logins and sets the variable.
Although, this does not work in Eclipse with M2E, even though it's set up to use the same Maven instance. So I tried to use Environment Variables Preference Page Eclipse plugin in order just to set a variable to a hardcoded value, but even that doesn't seem to work. If that was a constant, I would use an Info.plist file in the app, but it's a dynamic variable...
I hope some of you know a way around it. Thank you in advance!

You might consider to write an Eclipse plugin implementing the org.eclipse.core.variables.dynamicVariables extension point that retrieves the AWS Code Artifact Token, e.g. via the command line aws codeartifact get-authorization-token ... That way, you can set in the Maven run configuration an environment variable to this variable (you might start with setting the environment variable to the value ${string_prompt:Enter AWS Code Artifact Token} to get prompted each time you run the Maven build).

I found a way which involves restart of Eclipse, but this is at least something... This answer helped me. I basically created an executable (chmod +x) text file called eclipsebash in Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS folder with the following content:
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(dirname "$0")" || exit 1
cwd="$(pwd)"

export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain <my-domain> --domain-owner <my-aws-account> --region <my-aws-region> --query authorizationToken --output text`
export MVN_REPO_URL="https://my-codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/maven"

exec "${cwd}/eclipse"

Then I was able to run it from terminal using:
open Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipsebash

Although, when I tried to update it for the long-term to be able to run via Eclipse.app shortcut, it did not work. What I did was updated Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist file to have CFBundleExecutable key set to eclipsebash instead of eclipse. When I run it, I see MVN_REPO_URL variable is set, but CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN is blank. So looks like it does not execute that subcommand for aws codeartifact... I hope some of you know how to resolve it. Otherwise I have to run it from the terminal :(
Note 1: In order to check if environment variable is set, I used Eclipse -> About -> Installation Details -> Configuration tab - there is list of environment variables.
Note 2: For that to work, I have to manually run aws sso login once in a while (depending on your settings), so that aws codeartifact works. I tried to resolve this by adding conditional aws sso login to the same eclipsebash, but again - it only works if I run it from the terminal, it doesn't if I run it through the app shortcut.
